# Can you create a custom 404 page in SharePoint Online without using a publishing site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, 404

I have seen how this is possible by [modifying files on the server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/941329) or by [using a publishing site](https://gokan.azurewebsites.net/2014/01/05/custom-error-pages-on-sharepoint-2013/), but I need to do this for team sites within SharePoint Online.

Comment: Have you activated the publishing feature ? There is OOTB PageNotFoundError  page in the pages library. You can customize it like you do any publishing page.

Comment: Ah, I did not try just activating the publishing feature.  That may work well.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Darn, it looks like activating the publishing infrastructure does not enable the PageNotFoundError.aspx page.

Comment: Also activate the web level - SharePoint server publishing feature.

Comment: That did it!!!  So the answer is to activate the publishing infrastructure site collection feature AND the "SharePoint Server Publishing" site (SPWeb) feature.  @GautamSheth, feel free to create an answer so I can mark it correct as I think it is easier for others to find this way (than by looking in the comments).  I'll give you a couple of days and then I'll create the answer myself if you don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Activate the SharePoint server publishing infrastructure feature from site collection settings

[image]
 2. Activate the SharePoint server publishing feature

[image]

3. After activating these 2 features, Pages library will be created which contains the `PageNotFoundError.aspx` page. You can customize it as per your requirement.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! I'm using this as a friendly redirect. If the page doesn't exist but there is an "alias" list entry, this page sends them to their site

Answer (score 0):

You need publishing feature. If your site is created by team template, you have to activated this feature manually.

**Prerequisite** : you must be site collection admin.
**Steps to Activate** :

- Activate Site Collection Features: `https://{siteURL}/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site` find `SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure` feature and hit activate.
- Activate Site Features: `https://{SiteURL}/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx` and find `SharePoint Server Publishing` feature and hit activate.

**Verify:**
Go to this url : `https://{SiteURL}/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx` and find `PageNotFoundError.aspx`  created with "Error" pagelayout.

Now you can change this page according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can implement custom page not found error page without activating publishing feature! Here is how:

1. Navigate to your SharePoint Online site collection, Pick any document library (E.g. "Site Assets")
2. Enable Content type by: Click on Settings >> Library Settings >> Advanced Settings >> Set "Yes" for    "Allow management of content    types" option and click
   on "OK" in    the bottom of the page
3. In Library Settings    page, under    "Content Types", Click on "Add from existing site    content types" link    Add "Basic Page" content type to the Library.
4. Now, Go back to the    library >> Click on "New" >> Basic Page >> Give a name to your error     page (E.g. 404) and click on "Create"  Add some descriptive text    and image to the page and save!

Now, You have your custom error page ready. You can use either PowerShell or SharePoint Designer methods to set the custom page not found error page for SharePoint Online!

More Info Here: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/02/implement-custom-page-not-found-error-page-in-sharepoint-online.html